# Popup a menu error

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to popup a menu when a user presses the right mouse button on my listview. 
Here is my code:

```
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Me.cnmnuLstCopy.Show(Me.cnmnuLstCopy, e.Location)
    End If
```

I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because that code is trying to show the menu on the menu, not on the listview. The correct code is

```
Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Show(ListView1, e.Location)
```

You can actually pop up a context menu without any code. Simply add a context menu strip to your form and then on your listview, set the ContextMenuStrip property. No code required and it works  like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look on this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8756/Context-Menu-and-Event-Handling-in-Visual-Basic-NE).

sample code snippet:

```
Private Sub listView1_MouseUp(Byval Sender as Object, _
       Byval e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
       Handles listView1.MouseUp
  'Checking the Mouse right Button
  If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
    ContextHandler(listView1,e)
    listView1.ContextMenu.Show(listView1, New Point(e.X,e.Y))
  End if
End sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(Byval Sender as Object, _
       Byval e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
       Handles TextBox1.MouseUp

  'Checking the Mouse right Button
  If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
    ContextHandler(TextBox1,e)
    TextBox1.ContextMenu.Show(TextBox1, New Point(e.X,e.Y))
  End if
End sub
```